# Chromium webscrapping through Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: 22.04, gui, chromium

When I run chromium on Mobax , here is what I get:

```
MoTTY X11 proxy: No authorisation provided
[34343:34343:0216/222655.134781:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[34343:34343:0216/222655.134903:ERROR:env.cc(257)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

There is a .Xauthority file indeed in my root directory which is my user . I did also this command:

```
xauth list
```

and I copied the last line cookie and then I did this then:

```
xauth add THAT_COOKIE
```

However still I get the same error. I just want to run Chromium in a normal GPU mode,I want to see the GUI, I don't know why Linux does this to me LOL. It's **straightforward and trivial** in Windows servers.
Any solutions?

Note:
Other apps such as xeyes work nicely and I can see their GUI through my own pc .

Answer (score 0):

I used Google Chrome instead of Chromium and the problem get solved finally.